# More options at the bottom of the sharpoint page is not working

Tags: document-library, list-view

At the bottom of the sharepoint document library page more items buttons is there but when i click it nothing happens. I tried by changing the settings of Item limit and Folder options but nothing works.

Can any one let me know what is the quick fix for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Internet Explorer?
Did you check if Javascript is enabled?

Comment: Yes am using IE..

Comment: is there any option to fix this issue?

Comment: Are there any customization to your environment, specifically branding and/or custom JavaScript/jQuery? If IE finds a script error on your page, it'll discontinue processing JavaScript, and those buttons are merely JavaScript functions so it sounds like the script isn't running.

Comment: This Error occurs in only one sharePoint site..Is this somehting related to modifying the View?

Answer (score 1):

In your Internet Explorer, when you have the page open, press F12 (IE7 or later)

click on the Script Tab and then "Start debugging" . The page will reload.

click on the button that isn't working. Check the error in the right hand pane and report back the error message here so we can assist you.